# How do I match this in Backbone.js routes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
/story/:id
```

AND

```
/story/:id/:timestamp
```

I want both of these URLs to go to the same function in Backbone.js routes. (timestamp is optional)

What's the regex for this in Backbone.js?

Answer (score 4):

Just define two routes:

```
routes: {
    'story/:id':            'story',
    'story/:id/:timestamp': 'story',
    //...
}
```

The [`Backbone.Router.extend`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-extend) docs even include an example that is almost an exact match for your situation:

```
routes: {
  //[...]
  "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
  "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
},
```

And the [`routes` documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-routes) includes an example of a similar situation:

```
routes: {
  //[...]
  "folder/:name":       "openFolder",
  "folder/:name-:mode": "openFolder"
}
```